# How to get a method to print multiple arrays that aren't on the same line

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I'm writing a lab for my CS class, in this lab they want you to print the original array, scramble it, print it, sort it and then print it again. The thing is when I print out the arrays they all end up on the same line. I'm relatively new to java so if anybody could help that would be nice. Here is my code for the print method

```
private static int[] print(int[] lemons)
   {
      for(int k = 0; k < lemons.length; k++)
      {
         System.out.print(lemons[k] + " ");
      }
      return lemons;
   }
```

This is how it looks like when the array prints out: 
100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 108 105 104 103 101 102 100 107 106 109 100 101 103 102 104 105 107 106 109 108 (except in one big line)

This is how I want it too look like

- 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109,
- 104, 109, 106, 101, 103, 105, 107, 102, 108, 100,
- 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109,

Thanks!

Comment: You just need to add a blank `System.out.println()` call between calls to print each array.

Comment: Your code is not correct, and is not the code that shows the problem. The problem is where you call this code -- you need to put println's between those calls.

Comment: here's the thing I'm not allowed to change where the code is called since the teachers gave it to us set, here it is print(array);
      scramble(array);
      print(array);
      sort(array);
      print(array);

Comment: Then add a println at the end of your method above before the return statement.